# Swift Collection View With a Table View

Tags: ios, tableview, collectionview

I am looking to have a horizontal scrollable collection view inside of a table view. This horizontal collection view will be one of many rows in the table view. Here is a picture of what I have for my prototype cell.

[image]

Here is what it produces when I run it in the simulator (just shows the table view):

[image]

Here is what I want it to show:

[image]

I am not sure whether this is an issue in my code or whether it is something that can be fixed in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard create a prototype cell that contains a `UICollectionView` (Which you have already done). Set the `UIViewController` to be the `dataSource` of the `UICollectionView`and just add the required methods for the `UICollectionView`.

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //return the array showing number of collectionViewCells in tableViewCell. Of course you will have to handle the data showed in each tableView cell, (maybe using collectionView tags or some other logic)
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use only UICollectionView with customcell  instead of UITableView.
for example use following step for your output.

1 . Define datasourece method for collectionView .

2 . Put and customise below collectionView's layout delegate method as per your requirement

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2);
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/4 - 30, 150);//you need to resize  height and width as per your requirement.
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out below link.

["UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell"](https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/)

Tutorial covers how to add UICollectionView(For Horizontal Scrolling), inside a UITableViewCell.

Hope this helps, Cheers!!!!